# How to make one sql insert statement every 100 rows by DataGrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

After I upgraded to Mojave, Sequel Pro started to crash.
I am going to use DataGrip as the main database tool. But I have a problem that has not found a solution:
Datagrip → dump data to file → SQL Inerts

The insert statement generated by DataGrip looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO high_school_list (id, name) VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO high_school_list (id, name) VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO high_school_list (id, name) VALUES (3, 'c');
```

Such sql execution is very inefficient.
The insert statement generated by Sequel Pro is:

```
INSERT INTO high_school_list (id, name) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
```

How to set the datagrip to generate an Insert Sql format statement like Sequel Pro ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download this script file: https://gist.github.com/leo-from-spb/ec438f1fe9995b910ad816aabe47dd4f
2. Put it into a scripts folder (to locate it, press Go to scripts directory in the extractors drop-down).
3. Use this extractor.
   [image]

Comment: Hello, I have finished the above steps. Select " SQL - INSERT - STATEMENTS. SQL. Groovy" in Data Extractor, and then select Dump Data → To File again in the right-click menu, resulting in SQL text still being INSERT INTO per line.

Comment: You need to choose SQL-Inserts-MultiRowSynthax as I showed there on the pic

Answer (score 0):

A better solution which allows using batches rather than potentially trying to insert millions of rows all at once can be found here: [SQL Batch Multi-Line Insert](https://gist.github.com/ProjectCleverWeb/d2362b082af1d7054ebfd464f202ec1b)

This solution also has a bunch of other potentially useful configuration options, but the main feature is that it prevents locking tables for too long by inserting in batches instead of all at once.

#### How to install the script in DataGrip

1. Go to the "Data Extracters" dropdown. (in results bar)
2. Select "Go to Scripts Directory"
3. Create a new file called "SQL Batch Multi-Line Insert.sql.groovy"
4. Paste & save the script
5. (optional) Adjust the configuration variables